# Files in .git folder have wrong permissions after pushing to non-bare repository (receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead)

Tags: git

## Setup

I have a git repository on my work computer and a clone on my laptop.
I set `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead`.
This way I can push from my laptop to my work computer and git automaticaly updates the local files in my work directory there.

My work computer uses a NFS file system and per defaut everyone in the group has read permissions.

On my laptop, I have the remote configured with `username@computer:/home/path/to/git`

My colleges have their remote configured using `/path/to/home`

## The problem

Whenever I push to this non-bare repository, updated files in the .git folder (`.git/refs/heads/master`, `.git/objects/...`) get read permission for me, but not for the group. By default and before pushing, they had read permission for the group as well.

This way, my colleges cannot pull from my repository and get weird error messages.

## The question

Is there some setting that I can change to change this behavior?
Is this the intended behavior?
Or is there no solution to this except for filing a bug/ feature request with the git developers?

Comment: *NFS file system* How have you set up remote? With `/` or `file://` URL? Not `git://`, `git@`, `ssh://` or `http://`? What is your `umask` when you push to the repository?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I put the relevant info into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote URL `username@computer:/home/path/to/git` means that you use SSH, not NFS. You need to configure `umask` on the server side; try to edit it in `/home/username/.bash_profile` at the work computer.

You're also recommended to set

```
git config core.sharedRepository 0640
```

in the shared repository to make `git` to use this fixed `umask` instead of users' `umask`.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresharedRepository

Comment: My `umask` was set up correctly and the problem still occurred. But `git config core.sharedRepository 0640` did the trick.